# Web Service client on java, multiple calls to Service.create() case memory leak

Tags: java, web-services, memory-leaks

I found that the `javax.xml.ws.Service.create()` multiple calls case memory leak.

I solve that issue by reuse the result of this command.

I don't understand what was the reason of this memory leak, cause all the members that we declared is local (inside the one method).

```
public String callService()
{

  ...................

  QName serviceName = new QName( Url, "SERVICE_NAME"  );

  Service service = Service.create( serviceName );

  .......................

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you sure it's a memory leak?

Comment: I test it with JConsole and find that problem with Jprobe.

Comment: Nice work Boris. As a friendly reminder, can you please post an answer to the question yourself and then accept that answer so that we can close this question? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.